# Adding new line in datagrid view just below the current row in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a data grid view where i have a button column. I want to add a new row by clicking on button.

Generally this add new row in bottom of the datagrid view. I just want to add it just below to the current row where i clicked on button. Please help.

Regards,
Suraj

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the Button click event

`If DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 = Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index() Then
       Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index(), 1)
Else
     Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index() + 1, 1)
End If`

Comment: Thanks Venu, However i'm still unable to add the new row in datagrid view just below the current row. Reason is i'm using datagrid view which is bound with dataset. So i am using code me.tableAdapterBindingSource.AddNew. This code successfully add a new row in bottom. How can i make it added just below the current row in which button is clicked to add new row?